# undefined method `read_attribute_for_serialization' for #<Hash:0x00007fda56b4bc88>

Tags: ruby-on-rails, serialization

I am trying to set up a simple serialization. I have the following code:

```
def show
  @movie = Movie.find_by(id: params[:id])
  render json: { data: @movie }, serializer: MovieSerializer
end

class Movie < ActiveRecord::Base
  include ActiveModel::Serialization

  belongs_to :genre
  attr_accessor :rating, :plot, :poster
end

class MovieSerializer < ActiveModel::Serializer
  attributes :genre, :id

  belongs_to :genre
  attr_accessor :rating, :plot, :poster

  def genre
    'test'
  end
end
```

The controller raises an error

```
render json: { data: @movie }, serializer: MovieSerializer
undefined method `read_attribute_for_serialization' for #<Hash:0x00007fda56b4bc88>
```

And it seems that object is indeed a hash inside serializer.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [<NoMethodError: undefined method \`read\_attribute\_for\_serialization' for #<Record::ActiveRecord\_Relation:](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38510327/nomethoderror-undefined-method-read-attribute-for-serialization-for-record)

Answer (score 0):

removing the brackets have fixed the issue.

```
render json: @movie, serializer: MovieSerializer
```